# codeigniter session variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have create session array when login.
in session arrray i have set 'name' as key.
This is my controller's code.

```
$data = array();
$this->load->view('page', $data);
```

This is my view code.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=isset($name) ? $name : '' ?>">
```

when i use `<?=isset($name) ? $name : '' ?>`in my view file(without pass any data),then `$name` value autometically set from session.
I went to stop this.

Comment: `$this->session->userdata('name');`

Answer (score 0):

you need to access the session data like this

```
$this->session->userdata('name');
```

Code :

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?= isset($this->session->userdata('name')) ? $this->session->userdata('name') : '' ?>">
```

**Note :** session variable is globally accessible .

Comment: sorry for my bed english

Comment: but my <?=isset($name) ? $name : '' ?> code autometically set value from session , i don't need this value from session.

Comment: if you don't want that value means why your echoing remove everything `value=" "`

Answer (score 0):

- codeigniter do not auto get any data from session. check your
      $data variable
- It is possible that your browser Autocomplete form auto
          try something like this

  `<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />`